# How do I run patternview twice to Change a password using threads?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement a password change using patternview but if I use the code below the objects as designed, run separately and he second instance never loads. I am very new to android programming and java so please bear with my noobness...I am trying to get the code to input the two patterns, copy them to variables then compare them, I did not yet code the if statement below.

```
    public void changePassword (){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        patternLockView = findViewById(R.id.patternView);

        patternLockView.addPatternLockListener(new PatternLockViewListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStarted() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(List progressPattern) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(List pattern) {
                Pattern1 = PatternLockUtils.patternToString(patternLockView, pattern);
                Log.d("Pattern 1 = ", Pattern1);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCleared() {
            }
        });

        Toast.makeText(this, "Password 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        patternLockView.addPatternLockListener(new PatternLockViewListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStarted() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(List progressPattern) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(List pattern) {
                Pattern1 = PatternLockUtils.patternToString(patternLockView, pattern);
                Log.d("Pattern 2 = ", Pattern2);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCleared() {
            }

        });

        Toast.makeText(this, "Password Changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two activities 
Activityone - use patterlockview ,in onComplete method get the pattern and pass pattern data to second activity.

Activitytwo - getIntentdata in onCreate store it in variable
use one more patterlockview ,in onComplete method get the pattern data ,now compare stored data and current pattern data.